# How to run php with SimpleHTTPServer?

Tags: web-server, python

I just found [this awesome tip](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/5480/786) in the Apple SE:

> Start a quick webserver from any directory:
>
> ```
> python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
> ```

Is there a way to have this parse php scripts, or is this for html-only sites?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I just came across [this answer from StackOverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12235893/3392912)

Basically, python's webserver is not configured to run php files by default, but instead of trying to reconfigure python's web server, you can simply run php's web server, which works almost exactly like python's simplehttpserver, with

```
php [options] -S <addr>:<port> [-t docroot]
```

Example:

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:80 -t .
```

or simply

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:80
```

to use the current working directory.

Edit: Forgot to mention, it appears to be necessary to run this as root if you need to use port 80, but this is not necessary if you specify a higher port number like 8080. Thanks for pointing that out, Mike Houston!

Comment: Apparently, good things *do* come to those who wait :) Didn't even realize php had that functionality. Thanks!

Comment: @eykanal It's a new feature in PHP 5.4. :-)

Comment: You need to run as root if you want to use port 80, but if you choose a higher port number (e.g. 8080) you should be fine as a standard user.

Comment: Didn't know we have php on OSX by default. This is great.

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that the PHP web server is only for development purposes.. It does not have the extended features of say apache.. So for development yes.. For live sites NO!

Answer (score 4):

The [SimpleHTTPServer](http://docs.python.org/library/simplehttpserver.html) python library, called in that way, will only serve files, and will not interpret PHP (or python, for that matter).  However, you can get it to serve whatever you want (including PHP - check out [CGIHTTPServer](http://docs.python.org/library/cgihttpserver.html)) with some custom python wrapped around it.

Comment: So, as someone who doesn't know a stitch of python and doesn't really want to learn it right now, the answer is "no"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333632/cgihttprequesthandler-run-php-or-python-script-in-python

Comment: That's a "no", correct.